# Filtering a string list with logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of strings. I need to be able to filter them in a similar way to a Google query.

Ex: `NOT water OR (ice AND "fruit juice")`

Meaning return strings that do not have the word water or return strings that can have water if they have ice and "fruit juice".

Is there a mechanism in .NET that can allow the user to write queries in this form (say in a textbox) and given a List or IEnumerable of string, return the ones that contain this.

Can LINQ maybe do something like this?

I am aware that I can do this with LINQ, I'm more concerned with parsing an arbitrary string into an executable expression.

Comment: I am aware that I can do this with LINQ, I'm more concerned with parsing an arbitrary string into an executable expression.

Comment: I am quite surprised that .NET has nothing for token parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in.

You will need to parse such a string yourself and possibly use the [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) classes to build up an executable expression from which to filter.

Answer (score 1):

For this query: **Meaning return strings that do not have the word water or return strings that can have water if they have ice and "fruit juice".**

Try something like this if you are going to use `LINQ`

```
 yourList.Where(i => !i.Contains("water") || 
                (i.Contains("water") && 
                 i.Contains("ice") && 
                 i.Contains("fruit juice")));
```

Comment: You missed the `NOT` at the start. And this will not help with _any other input_

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ: `list.Where(item => !item.Contains("water") || (item.Contains("ice") && item.Contains("fruit juice")))`

Comment: And when the user inputs something else?

Comment: @Oded yeah I did not realize the question was about parsing a query from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't answer you using a code sample since as you said this is more logical.

what I would do in such a scenario is to have predefined conditions (saved somewhere) which will contain all the conditions you need along with their "coding translations" like:

- and
- or
- and not
- and or
- etc...

and what you will do at runtime is to translate these conditions/criteria into sql or linq or whatever language you need to pass it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `DataTable.Select` method:

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, string expression) {
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));

    foreach (var item in self) {
      var row = table.NewRow();
      row["Value"] = item;
      table.Rows.Add(item);
    }

    return table.Select(expression).Select(row => (T)row["Value"]);
  }

}
```

But you have to follow its format to create your expression:

```
var filtered = strings.Select("NOT Value LIKE '*water*' OR (Value LIKE '*ice*' AND Value LIKE '*fruit juice*')");
```

Also note that in this case, since the string `fruit juice` already contains the string `ice`, the second condition is redundant. You'd have to find a way to express "words" and not "substrings".

In the end, you might be better off implementing the parsing logic yourself.